# how to keep record of the email invited by member of my website

Tags: php, email

We have a sponsorship system in our website.
A person A is a member of our website. A can invite B. If B joins our site, we will give referral points to A.

My problem: how will I track when B joins our website that B was invited by A?

We are sending invitations through email via a link to the signup page for our website.

A secondary problem: how do I tell A if B is already a member of our website?
And what if A wants to invite all of his friends from any mailer system like Yahoo or Gmail?

I'm very confused so if anyone can clear at least one point up, it is a great help for me.
Thank you so much for your time and attention.

Answer (score 1):

Every member should have their own invitation link, so every time some new users register with your site via the member invitation link, the script adds some points to the invitation link owner.

Comment: @Peteris it means i have to generate user specific invitation ok let me try this Thank you so much for immediate response

Comment: you could make the link for example http://yourpage/register/<MemberIdHere> (or if you don't use 'friendly urls' - http://yourpage/register.php?m=<MemberIdHere> so after successfull registration some points should be added to `$_GET['m']` (id in (for example) user table) ;]

Comment: +1 because @Omprks doesn't know how to upvote or accept answers to help those that help him.

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic ways:

**First**

You create a unique referal ID that is beeing stored in db with all the dat, meaning, it contains who sent the email, when, etc. After that, you just give the ID to a link, that has to be used

**Second**

This is simpler, you just privide the user_id as your referal ID in the link sent to person B. This way you don't need to store anything in your db.

Comment: i think second one is better let me try this thank you so much for your help

Comment: +1 because @Omprks doesn't know how to accept or upvote answers to help those that help him.

Answer (score 0):

Two options I can think of:

1. Tell members that if they want the points they should use a special URL generated for them. Give each member a unique code and include it in the url, that way when B comes you know it's from A. If A wants to send from a different system the special generated link should be used.
2. Tell users invite only through your system to get points - save which member invited which email address. When B registers with an Email address you'll know A invited him. Moreover, You'll know A was the first to invite him if other members sent invitations as well.